# git pulling FROM a specific branch TO a specific branch

Tags: git

We are using a github repo as our "central repository".

We are planning to have multiple coders working on the staging server in the following manner:

1. Coders work on a separate branch on their local repo;
2. Coders push changes to github; and then
3. Coders pull updates from github to server repo

So, in practice, on Step 3, coders will run the following on the staging repo:

`git checkout coderA-updates`
`git pull origin coderA-updates`
`git checkout master`

Is there a way to update a specific branch without having to `git checkout` it first?

---

TLDR:
How do you do something like `git pull origin remoteBranch localBranch` without having to switch active branches?

Thanks :)

Comment: what you mean by "update a specific branch"? The only branch that has their files in a usable state is the current branch that's been checked out. If you want to update the internal repo, git fetch will do that for other branches too, but without a branch being current you wouldn't be able to work with the files anyway. In short, you can update any branch you want or all the branches, but only current branch has its files usable.

Comment: Hi eis. By "update a specific branch" i meant update the branch by getting the latest commits from github. I only want to update the branch, I do not need the files to be usable. How do you use git fetch to only update a specific branch? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout branchB
git pull origin branchA
```

This gets changes which happened in `branchA` and merges them into local `branchB`.

`git help merge` says:

> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their
>   histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.

So, i believe it is impossible to work with 2 branches without making one of them current.

You can use `git stash` in your currently active branch to save the changes and then checkout `branchB` and pull `branchA`. After the merge is done, you checkout the branch where you stashed changes and use `git stash apply`.

Or you can simply commit the changes before checkingout/pulling.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sergey. This changes the currently active branch though. I would like to have it so that the currently active branch stays intact

Comment: My problem is when there are 2 coders pulling. Say coderA works on branchA and coderB works on branchB. When coderA is in the middle of testing branchA, coderB would have to wait until coderA is finished testing first before he can pull anything to branchB. Thanks btw :)

Comment: @Bibokid you mean those two coders are working on the same file system? Can you clarify that a bit further in the question?

Comment: @eis: 2 coders pushing, pulling, testing updates on the server

Answer (score 1):

Use a plain `fetch`:

```
git fetch origin remoteBranch:localBranch
```

This will only work for fast-forward changes by default (see the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)).

Answer (score 0):

From `git help pull`:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> [...]
>
> can name an arbitrary remote ref (for example, the name of a
>   tag) or even a collection of refs with corresponding remote-tracking
>   branches (e.g., refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*), but usually it is
>   the name of a branch in the remote repository.

So, you can do `git pull remoteBranch:localBranch` and it will work.

Comment: i tried `git pull origin remoteBranch:localBranch` but error: rejected (non-fastforward) although i am sure `localBranch` is an earlier version of `remoteBranch`

Comment: Try looking commits' hashes. Maybe there was a `git rebase` or something like that that affected hashes.

Comment: `git pull` will always merge into the locally checked out branch, even if you provide a full "remote:local" refspec. From the docs: "More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch."