# Is there a way to pull/merge from a remote repo (github, in this case) into a different branch than the local one?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to use Github hooks to update my server repo whenever I push a change there. The problem I'm facing is that sometimes that repository might be in a different branch than the one updated in Github. Example:

- Server repo is in "master" branch
- Branch "development" is updated in Github
- Github fires web hook
- hook pulls from github, **but changes land in master rather than in development**

What's in bold is basically the problem, and I don't want to make the hook script change the current branch in order to update.
I tried this:

```
git pull origin development:development
```

but then development was pulled correctly, **and** merged into master.

I checked already this question:

[git pulling FROM a specific branch TO a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453436/git-pulling-from-a-specific-branch-to-a-specific-branch#comment-18422202)

(After trying the above, of course) and it seem there is no way to do it with pull.
But merges also work only in the current branch? (Probably that's why pull doesn't work either)

So, is there a way to do this, or not?

Answer (score 0):

After you "pull and merge", you can reset the original branch back to where it was.  Or you can clone to a new repository, create/merge to the target branch, then push that new repository's branch into your original repository.  Remember that "branches" in git aren't anything magical, they're just labels (pointers) to a particular commit hash.  You can move them around as needed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pull and merge". Also (and it's something I forgot in my original question, apologies on that) this is a live server, so I can't go around cloning repos. As the site is being used (it's not the master server, but I "share" it with 4 other coders) and sometimes is in a rather dirty state (with files edited directly in the server) I don't think switching branches will be harmless. Yep, it's a mess.

Comment: By "pull and merge" I meant the "pull into other branch that automatically merges original branch" -- the solution you don't like.  It's ok that it's a live server, though if you don't want to clone onto that server, clone locally, make the change, and publish it -- either to the "live" server or to the original repo.